# forgot password query failure due to multiple 'and' & or 'claws'

Tags: c#, html, sql

```
<TD> 
    con.Open();
    string sql = "select password from Login_user where user_name='" + txtname.Text + "' and mobile='" + txtmob.Text + "'  and security_question='" + cmbquestion.SelectedText + "' and answer='" + txtanswer.Text + "' || user_name='" + txtname.Text + "' and dob='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "'  and security_question='" + cmbquestion.SelectedText + "' and answer='" + txtanswer.Text + "'";

    //string sql1 = "select password from Login_user where user_name='" + txtname.Text + "' and mobile='" + txtmob.Text + "' and security_question='" + cmbquestion.SelectedText + "' and answer='" + txtanswer.Text + "'";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read() == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your Password is : " + dr.GetString(0) + ".", "SUCCESSFUL !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        con.Close();
        this.Hide();
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.Show();

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NOT found");
    }

    con.Close();
    dr.Close();
</TD>
```

i have given a c# code where i have taken  query to show a password in a password      recovery form and i want all the fields to be compulsory, but only the two fields that are mobile and dob will be either or condition.so any one of them will be given to submit.what will be the code please provide me the correct query for this functionality.

Comment: It looks like you might need parenthesis around the different parts of your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group mobile and dob together within parenthesis and an `OR` clause.

Besides that, you really need to structure your query so it can be read easier and use parameters for better security and performance.

Try this:

```
 string sql = @"
 select password 
 from Login_user 
 where  user_name=@user_name 
   and  (
            mobile=@mobile 
            OR
            dob=@dob
        )
   and  security_question=@security_question
   and  answer=@answer ";

cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@user_name", txtname.Text);
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtmob.Text);
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@answer", txtanswer.Text);
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@security_question", cmbquestion.SelectedText);
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@dob", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
```